# How to create a list of igraphs from ncol files?

Tags: r, list, igraph

I have a number of weighted graphs stored in `*.ncol` files. For the sake of the question lets say I have 2 files,

**ncol_1.ncol**

```
21 53 1.0
5 52 1.0
32 52 1.0
119 119 0.5
119 85 0.5
87 0 1.0
36 116 1.0
85 87 1.0
116 5 1.0
4 52 1.0
115 4 1.0
53 115 1.0
52 36 0.3333333333333333
52 21 0.3333333333333333
52 119 0.3333333333333333
```

**ncol_2.ncol**

```
21 115 1.0
119 85 1.0
87 0 1.0
85 87 1.0
4 48 0.3333333333333333
4 20 0.6666666666666666
115 4 1.0
55 119 1.0
48 4 1.0
20 4 0.25
20 20 0.25
20 21 0.25
20 55 0.25
0 20 1.0
```

I would like to read these into a list of graphs, that is I would like to have a list where `my_graphs[1]` would give me the graph from **ncol_1.ncol**

(I've crossed over from Python so my go to data structure is a list, I am open to a better R solution if one exists)

My attempt in R,

```
library(igraph)

f_list <- list.files(pattern = "\\.ncol$")
set.seed(123)
my_graphs <- list(length(f_list)

g_count = 1
for (f in f_list){
  print(f)
  my_graphs[g_count] <- read.graph(f, format = "ncol", directed = T)
  g_count = g_count + 1
}
```

This is what I get as output,

```
[1] "r_test_1_0_100.ncol"
[1] "r_test_1_0_125.ncol"
Warning messages:
1: In my_graphs[g_count] <- read.graph(f, format = "ncol", directed = T) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In my_graphs[g_count] <- read.graph(f, format = "ncol", directed = T) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> my_graphs[1]
[[1]]
[1] 13
```

So what am I doing wrong here? Is the `list` initialization wrong? is this something that just cant be done? am I expecting Pythonic behaviour where none exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `list`, you should use

```
my_graphs[[g_count]] <- read.graph(f, format = "ncol", directed = T)
```

or

```
my_graphs[g_count] <- list(read.graph(f, format = "ncol", directed = T))
```

Comment: Is there any good documentation about `igraph` available somewhere?

Comment: @AnilGoyal I think the best is to read the manual or read other's code in SO  :)

Comment: I get a list of someting using this but they doesn't behave like `igraph` objects eg if I try `plot(my_graphs[1], vertex.size=24)` it throws an error

Comment: @DrBwts Try `my_graphs[[1]]`